# Select-list echo's multiple times instead of once

Tags: php

I have a select-list which when selected, echo's a form with another select-list in it. But instead of showing me just one select-list it shows twice the same select-list. Anybody who knows why this happens?

**Selectlist:**

```
echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">';
echo '<label for="selectlist">Lend devices:</label>';
echo    '<select name="selectlist" id="selectlist" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" onchange="GrabRegDevice(this.value);">';
echo        '<option value="" disabled selected>Name devices</option>';
$db = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$db) {
    exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$querylenddevices = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE orgnaam = '" . $q . "'";
$db = mysqli_query($db,$querylenddevices);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo "<option value='".$d['devicename']."'>".$d['devicename']."</option>";
}
echo    '</select>';
echo '</div>';
```

**Edit:**
Here is the whole .PHP file

```
<?php require 'database.php';

$q=$_GET["q"];    
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM register WHERE orgnaam = '" . $q . "'";  
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">';
    echo    '<label for="naam">Organisatie naam:</label>';
    echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="orgnaam" name="orgnaam" value="' . $row['orgnaam'] . '">';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">';
    echo    '<label for="adres">Organisatie adres:</label>';
    echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="adres" name="adres" value="' . $row['orgadres'] . '">';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">';
    echo    '<label for="postcode">Organisatie postcode:</label>';
    echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="postcode" name="postcode" value="' . $row['orgpostcode'] . '">';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">';
    echo    '<label for="woonplaats">Organisatie woonplaats:</label>';
    echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="woonplaats" name="woonplaats" value="' . $row['orgwoonplaats'] . '">';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">';
    echo    '<label for="telnummer">Organisatie telefoonnummer:</label>';
    echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="telnummer" name="telnummer" value="' . $row['orgtel'] . '">';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
    echo    '<label for="">Naam contactpersoon:</label>';
    echo    '<input type="naamcontact" class="form-control" readonly id="naamcontact" name="naamcontact" value="' . $row['naamcontact'] . '">';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
    echo    '<label for="emailcontact">Email contactpersoon:</label>';
    echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="emailcontact" name="emailcontact" value="' . $row['emailcontact'] . '">';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
    echo    '<label for="telcontact">Telefoonnummer contactpersoon:</label>';
    echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="telcontact" name="telcontact" value="' . $row['telcontact'] . '">';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">';
    echo '<label for="selectlist">Lend devices:</label>';
    echo    '<select name="selectlist" id="selectlist" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" onchange="GrabRegDevice(this.value);">';
    echo        '<option value="" disabled selected>Name devices</option>';
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    if (!$db) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $querylenddevices = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE orgnaam = '" . $q . "'";
    $db = mysqli_query($db,$querylenddevices);
    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
        echo "<option value='".$d['devicename']."'>".$d['devicename']."</option>";
    }
    echo    '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

**Edit 2**
When in the database 'register' contains e.g. 3 devices, it shows 3 times the select-list. Could this happen because i don't use an ID in option value?

Comment: If the main `php` function/result is `echoed` in only one `option` why are you `echoing` the other `div`?

Comment: what other div do you mean?

Comment: starting from `<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">`. do you have any other `php` code above

Comment: Yes i'll edit my post wait a second please

Comment: Since `$db` variable is already used to connect to `database` try using a different variable name to `msqli_query`

Comment: Ok thanks i'll try it

Comment: Hmm that doesn't makes any sense unfortunately @OkeTega

Comment: It does make great sense: `$opts = mysqli_query($db,$querylenddevices);     while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($opts)) {`

Comment: I just tried using an `sqlite3 database` and it didn't `echo` twice. Please check your database to see if you don't have two rows with the value of `$q`

Comment: It does have two rows with the value of $q, but it is the meaning that it shows all the names of the devices $q has lend. So $q is multiple times in the database. Any idea how I can handle this? Maybe something with the query?

Comment: It just shows me 2 select-lists with both the separate values, but I want those both values in 1 select-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the whole select-list was set in a while loop. So for each devicename it makes another select-list. Now i echo the select-list outside my while loop and only put the  in a while loop. Here is my code:

```
<?php require 'database.php';


$q=$_GET["q"];

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM register WHERE orgnaam = '" . $q . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">';
echo    '<label for="naam">Organisatie naam:</label>';
echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="orgnaam" name="orgnaam" value="' . $row['orgnaam'] . '">';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">';
echo    '<label for="adres">Organisatie adres:</label>';
echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="adres" name="adres" value="' . $row['orgadres'] . '">';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">';
echo    '<label for="postcode">Organisatie postcode:</label>';
echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="postcode" name="postcode" value="' . $row['orgpostcode'] . '">';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">';
echo    '<label for="woonplaats">Organisatie woonplaats:</label>';
echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="woonplaats" name="woonplaats" value="' . $row['orgwoonplaats'] . '">';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">';
echo    '<label for="telnummer">Organisatie telefoonnummer:</label>';
echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="telnummer" name="telnummer" value="' . $row['orgtel'] . '">';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
echo    '<label for="">Naam contactpersoon:</label>';
echo    '<input type="naamcontact" class="form-control" readonly id="naamcontact" name="naamcontact" value="' . $row['naamcontact'] . '">';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
echo    '<label for="emailcontact">Email contactpersoon:</label>';
echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="emailcontact" name="emailcontact" value="' . $row['emailcontact'] . '">';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
echo    '<label for="telcontact">Telefoonnummer contactpersoon:</label>';
echo    '<input type="" class="form-control" readonly id="telcontact" name="telcontact" value="' . $row['telcontact'] . '">';
echo '</div>';

}
echo '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">';
        $querytest = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE orgnaam = '" . $q . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $querytest);
echo    '<label for="selectlist">Geleende apparaten:</label>';
echo        '<select name="selectlist" id="selectlist" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" onchange="GrabRegDevice(this.value);">';
echo            '<option value="" disabled selected>Naam apparaat</option>';
                    while($rowtest = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $rowtest['apparaatnaam'] . "'>" . $rowtest['apparaatnaam'] . "</option>";
                    }
echo        '</select>';
echo '</div>';

?>
```